# What is the easiest way to host a CD-ROM drive or ISO through a network (for booting/install)

Tags: boot, networking, iso

So this is something ive wanted to learn (Network booting) but It seems everytime I look it up, there is something unnecessarily complex or its just obscure, So I figure id post it here and try to find something a little more intelligible for others that might search... as well as learn myself.

So can anyone point me to a cross-platform method of booting through a network?

Answer (score 0):

The thing you are looking for it called setup **PXE Install server**. It allows you to mount .iso and allows you to setup network installation on your network. Check out [this documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PXEInstallServer).